# Access state from component in another tab in React native

Tags: react-native, state, setstate, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

In my app I have two components in different tabs, **BookShelf** and **AddBook**. BookShelf contains a FlatList of books added by the user and my idea with AddBook is to search for books and press a button to add it to the list in the BookShelf component.

My idea is to store the books as objects in an array in the BookShelfs state. Is it possible to access the state of BookShelf from AddBook, and how would I do this? I tried to create a function in BookShelf that updates the state and pass it as props to my AddBook component without success since I have to render the AddBook component in BookShelf to pass the props.

Right now I'm using a TabNavigator for the tabs, where separate StackNavigators are nested in the tabs.

**Tree structure:**

**START:** App.js -> TabsNavigator -> **TABS:** BookShelf & AddBook

**TAB 1:** BookShelf -> **STACK:** BookShelfStack -> **COMPONENTS:** BookShelf & BookInfo

**TAB 2:** AddBook -> **STACK:** AddBookStack -> **COMPONENTS:** AddBook

**Router.js handling the navigation:**

```
export const BookShelfStack = createStackNavigator({
BookShelf: {
    screen: BookShelf,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Book Shelf',
    }

},

BookInfo: {
    screen: BookInfo,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Book Info'
    }
},   
})

export const AddBookStack = createStackNavigator({
AddBook: {
    screen: AddBook,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Add Book',
    }
}

})

export const TabsNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({

'BookShelf': {
    screen: BookShelfStack,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Book Shelf',
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => <Icon name="ios-book" type="ionicon" size={28} color={tintColor}/>
    }
},

'AddBook': {
    screen: AddBookStack,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Add Book',
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => <Icon name="ios-add-circle-outline" type="ionicon" size={28} color={tintColor}/>
    }
},
});
```

**BookShelf component with placeholder data right now:**

```
export default class BookShelf extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.addBook = this.addBook.bind(this);

this.state = {

    books: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire',
            author:'J.K. Rowling',
            thumbnail:'https://covers.openlibrary.org/w/id/7984916-M.jpg',
        },

        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'The Hobbit',
            author: 'J.R.R. Tolkien',
            thumbnail:'https://covers.openlibrary.org/w/id/6979861-M.jpg'
        },

        {
            id: 3,
            title: '1984',
            author: 'George Orwell',
            thumbnail:'https://covers.openlibrary.org/w/id/7222246-M.jpg'
        }

    ]
}
}

renderBook = ({item}) => (

    <BookShelfItem
    navigation={this.props.navigation}
    id={item.id}
    title={item.title}
    author={item.author}
    thumbnail={item.thumbnail}
    />
);

addBook(book) {

    let updatedBookList = this.state.books.slice();
    updatedBookList.push(book);

    this.setState({
        books: updatedBookList    
    });
}

render() {
    const {container} = styles;
    <AddBook addBook={this.addBook}/>
    return (
        <View style={container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content"/>
         <FlatList
        data={this.state.books}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={this.renderBook}
        extraData={this.state.books}
        /> 
        </View>

    );
}
}
```

**AddBook component where I try to receive addBook function as props from BookShelf:**

```
export default class AddBook extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props)
}

render() {
    const {container, title, textInputStyle} = styles;
    const { addBook } = this.props;
    return (
        <View style={container}>
        <Text style={title}>
        Add Book
        </Text>
        <TextInput style={textInputStyle}
        placeholder = {'Search books..'}
        />
        <Button 
        title = "Add book"
        onPress={() => addBook}

        />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Please add the code, what have you tried and where you are getting the issue.

Comment: Updated with my code.

Comment: Can you also post the tree of the components?

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean with tree of components?

Comment: Correction, tree structure. Parent -> Stack -> tab -> Component

Comment: I added the structure in the original post. I hope it is understandable.

Comment: Passing params between two separate stack navigators nested in tab navigators might be achievable using redux.   Redux solve your problem because your able to access your own 'state' from any 'view/component' .  Or your could use a 'singleton' pattern to be able to access the 'state' as well